# joomla - create a plugin that changes pages title & description

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm a joomla noob, and I know how to create a content joomla plugin that prints text just after article title using event listener `onContentAfterTitle`. [Content plugin for Joomla](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-plugin/hello-world)

But I cant find the `event listener` inside which I should put my code that changes pages `title` & page `description`. I have put it inside `onContentPrepare` & in the `onAfterDispatch`but it doesnt work.

Anyone can explain to me how to get it work?

**P.S:** I want to create the plugin myself to customize as I want

Comment: You might want to show us some code. Does your plugin install in /plugins/content/ ? http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events lists onContentAfterTitle for J3.x only and for managing IntroText, you should set document title in onDocumentBeforeDisplay - and it will work also in J2.5

Comment: For description do you mean metadata?

Comment: @RiccardoZorn, @Elin: It should be a `system` plugin. I was asking about the html metatag `description` & `title` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link, but I've found an answer to my question here:
[Create a plugin that changes pages title & meta description](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/q-waslPCMpk)

And the event in which to put the code is `onBeforeCompileHead`, and the function used to alter head is: `$document->setHeadData($headData);`.